# tcp connection works from out of node while readinessProbe fails

Tags: kubernetes

I have an apache pod with 80 port exposed.

It could be accessed from out of the node.

```
kubectl port-forward svc/apache-service 8081:80
curl -I localhost:8081

...
200 OK
```

But Readiness probe fails.

`Readiness probe failed: dial tcp 192.168.6.108:80: i/o timeout`

I don't know why this is happening.

Comment: Can you provide pod/deployment, service definition + Dockerfile of apache container?

Answer (score 0):

problem solved.
It was because the coredns was broken.

Comment: What has to do coredns with your issue? Readiness probes are done by kubelet, on a path, socket or linux command. Where is playing coredns?